# Leaflet map tiles not loading in bootstrap modal with onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a big problem. The issue is that when I press the button and the modal opens the map tiles don't load completely.

my html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success pull-left" onClick="return map()"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> openMap</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="mapModal">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="address-label">modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="map"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="return map()">add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript code:

```
function map(){
$('#mapModal').modal();
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        });
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [35.7219, 51.3347],
            zoom: 10,
            layers: [osm]
        });
}
```

Please help and give the correct answer.

The image below shows the bug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QirsQ.png)

Comment: How about creating the issue here https://jsfiddle.net/ and sharing that as well

Comment: In jsfiddle, the error was not displayed. But I posted a picture of the error. @Kevon